# Autohotkey does suspend on its own

Tags: autohotkey

This is the whole script:

```
capslock::
Send {Media_Play_Pause}

F2::
Suspend
return
```

The problem is after I press capslock, the media player (media monkey or windows media player) will pause as well as the scipt will be suspended.

There's no other AHK script running, only this one.

Comment: You forgot to add "return" at the end of the first hotkey assignment. Return stops code from going any further, to the lines below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
capslock::
Send {Media_Play_Pause}
return

F2::
Suspend
return
```

You forgot to `return` in the 1st hotkey definition.